# Delete File from Directory asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, io

I am displaying the images of a directory on the site and the user can upload and delete the contents of this folder. However, for some reason my delete link button is not working. 
Here is my code to display the Images (It works no issues):

```
{
            string[] filesindirectory = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Products/"));
            List<String> images = new List<string>(filesindirectory.Count());

            foreach (string item in filesindirectory)
            {
                images.Add(String.Format("~/Images/Products/{0}", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item)));
            }
            ListView1.DataSource = images;
            ListView1.DataBind();
        }
```

Here is my code for the Delete Link Button (This is not working):

```
protected void deleteLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var deleteButton = sender as LinkButton;
        string[] filesindirectory = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Products/{0}"));
        try
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Products/"));
            fi.Delete();
            statusLabel2.Text = "Delete Image Successful!";
        }
        catch
        {
            // Display error
            statusLabel2.Text = "Delete Image Failed";
        }
        ListView1.DataBind();
    }
```

When I try to delete a file I am receiving this error:
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path

And my stack trace is displaying:

System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +359
   System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit() +268
   System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost) +445
   System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(String path) +70

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specify invalid search path `"~/Images/Products/{0}"` which gives you the error - not sure what it should be.

You are trying to delete directory as file - hence the next error would be on this line:

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Products/"));
fi.Delete()
```

Comment: Okay you are going to have to excuse that I am kind of new to all this. Are you saying that, that line is telling it to delete my directory and not the file in the directory? Because I want to delete the selected file from the directory, not the directory. How do I get it to find the selected file?

Comment: @Faron - just `Path.Combine` the directory to file name you want to delete. (How to get value from view/form to server is separate question asked many times before).

Answer (score 1):

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Products/"));
```

here you try to initiate a directory as file

```
string[] filesindirectory = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Products/{0}"));
```

and here your have a invalid directory-path - this one throws your exception